# Foregin Keys in NEW phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin, wamp

I'm really desperate. I had to reinstall my old wamp server for the newest one and now I don't know how to work with foreign keys in phpmyadmin. Now, I have Wamp 3.0.0 with MySQL 5.7.9.

I have 2 tables - users, profiles. In profiles I have a column named user_id which has to reference to users table. How can I do this?

In old phpmyadmin, I just clicked on relation view and there i saw all options for setting foreing keys. But in this new phpmyadmin I don't have such an option.Now, it looks like this:
[image: new phpMyAdmin]

When I click on "Relation view" button, I get something like this:
[image]

But where Can I simply add foreign keys to users table? What I have to do?
Of course I have set InnoDB on all tables, primary keys on profiles (id) and users(id), user_id in profiles table is unique.

And my second question is - where can the list of all foreign keys in table?

Comment: The relation view lets you add a constraint (foreign key). In the second screenshot you posted you can enter a constraint name, column to put the constraint on and select the table + column the constraint should use.

Comment: So, you are telling me, that I have already created foreing key to table user? It's strange, because in my PHP application it doesn't work..

Comment: You're using the `foreign key constraints`. There is a `Internal Relations` portion above the `Foreign Key constraints` portion. That's where you set your foreign key visually.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand you now. Where is Internal Relations portion ?? I don't see it anywhere. In old phpMyAdmin, when I clicked on "Indexes" - there were a list of all foreign keys. But in this new version, when I click on Indexes there is just PRIMARY KEY (id) and UNIQUE (user_id), nothing more.. There should be all the foregin keys, too, shouldn't they?

Comment: What version of `Phpmyadmin` are you using by the way? See image [here](http://tinypic.com/r/2mes6l4/9)

Comment: PhpMyAdmin version 4.5.1 .. Well, that's the problem - I don't have there internal relations portion.. Don't you know teel me, how's that possible?

Comment: We have the same exact version although I am using it on `XAMPP`. So, it should be there.

Comment: Anybody else with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

**Change your storage engine to InnoDB by going to Operation.**

You could simply run the following SQL query on SQL tab after selecting the desired database from phpMyAdmin.

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ENGINE = InnoDB
```

After the execution of this query the database engine of the selected database will be changed to InnoDB.

---

Also, we do have another method.

1. Login to your phpMyAdmin.
2. Select the database table from the left hand column whose storage engine need to be changed.
3. Click on the Operations tab.
4. Under Table options, you would find a drop down called Storage Engine.
5. Select the Storage Engine of your choice.
6. when you are done, click on GO.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it also manually instead of visually.

```
ALTER TABLE profiles ADD CONSTRAINT fk_users_id 
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)
```

Comment: I tried this too. But I got this error:  #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: Make sure that your `user_id` in `users` table has the same data type as `user_id` in `profiles` table.

Comment: Man, I really appreciate your help :) .. Anyway, user_id in profiles and id in users are the same type - int (11) .. Still don't know where it doesn't work.. Maybe it will help, but I don't have Internal RElations portion in any table

Comment: Are your tables also both `INNODB`? Kindly check.

Comment: Maybe the columns are signed/unsigned?

Comment: No .. there will be some problem with the whole phpMyAdmin, because foreign keys doesn't work in any project ... there's just missing Internal Relations portion